# Does PagingData Run on a Background Thread by Default in Paging 3 Library?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-paging, android-thread

**Is background threading managed automatically with `PagingData` as it is with `PagedList`, and then returned on the main thread?**

From the logs below, it appears `PagingData` is not run on the backgroud thread in the Paging 3 library compared to `PagedList` in Paging 2's library.

**Expect** (*Based on the [Paging Codelab](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-paging) sample*)

- *GithubPagingSource* `override suspend fun load(...)` to run on an IO thread.
- *SearchRepositoriesActivity* `viewModel.searchRepo(query).collectLatest { ... }` to run on the main thread.

**Observe**

- Both *GithubPagingSource* `override suspend fun load(...)` and *SearchRepositoriesActivity* `viewModel.searchRepo(query).collectLatest { ... }` run on the main thread.

## Paging 2

Threading is handled on the background by `PagedList` with `toLiveData` according to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/paging/PagedList#loading-data).

> If you use LivePagedListBuilder to get a LiveData, it will initialize PagedLists on a background thread for you.

## Paging 3

The Paging 3 [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/paging/PagingData) does not mention how threading is managed. However, from the logs, `PagingSource` appears to be running the network request on a main thread and returning the `PagingData` on a main thread.

### My Sample Code

I've recreated the Codelab pattern in the [CryptoTweets](https://github.com/AdamSHurwitz/CryptoTweets) sample app *app-simple* module.

*FeedPagingSource.kt*

```
class FeedPagingSource : PagingSource<Int, Tweet>() {

    override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, Tweet> {
        try {
            val page = params.key ?: 1
            val nextPage = page + 1
            val tweets = Injection.feedService.getTweets(...)
            println("Thread: FeedPagingSource ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "load success: ${tweets}")
            return LoadResult.Page(...)
        } catch (error: Exception) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

*FeedRepository.kt*

```
class FeedRepository {
    fun initFeed() = Pager(
        config = PagingConfig(pageSize = FEED_PAGEDLIST_SIZE),
        pagingSourceFactory = { FeedPagingSource() }
    ).flow
}
```

*FeedViewModel.kt*

```
repository.initFeed().onEach {
    println("Thread: FeedViewModel ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
    _feed.value = it
}.launchIn(viewModelScope)
```

### Attempted Solution

In order to run the `PagingSource` on a background thread, the flow is initiated on `Dispatchers.IO`. However, the log still shows `PagingSource` runs on the main thread in *FeedPagingSource.kt*.

*FeedViewModel.kt*

```
repository.initFeed().onEach {
            println("Thread: FeedViewModel ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
            _feed.value = it
}.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO).launchIn(viewModelScope)
```

Comment: Try `.launchIn(viewModelScope  + Dispatchers.IO)`

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation @IR42. However, this results in the flow data emitting on the IO thread, `DefaultDispatcher-worker-1`, and the `PagingSource` still running on `main` in the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Kotlin Coroutines

When implementing `PagingData` and `PagingSource` with Kotlin Coroutines and making a Retrofit network request, as in the sample code above, Retrofit handles the background threading by default and returns on the main thread.

*See StackOverflow: [Does Retrofit make network calls on main thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63986072/2253682)*

## RxJava

When using RxJava with Retrofit as the network source, the threading needs to be explicitly specified as shown in the Android documentation sample.

*See Android documentation: [Page from network and database](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-network-db) > [Implement a RemoteMediator](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-network-db#implement-remotemediator)*

Comment: what about room?!

Comment: @A.sobhdel according to the Coroutines codelabs [here](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-coroutines#8) Room uses a custom dispatcher

Answer (score 7):

It is not running on background thread in Paging 3, even I use `lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO)` in the view model, as the PagingSource is accessed from Main thread when adapter loads. So for Room, I get it working by wrapping the PagingSource database code inside `withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {`

```
private const val STARTING_PAGE_INDEX = 0
private const val COUNT_PER_PAGE = 20

class LocalImagesPagingSource() : PagingSource<Int, GalleryImage>() {

    override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, GalleryImage> {
        val page = params.key ?: STARTING_PAGE_INDEX
        return try {
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                val dao = GalleryImageDatabase.getDatabase(context).galleryImageDao()
                val images = dao.getGalleryImagesByPosition(page * COUNT_PER_PAGE)

                LoadResult.Page(
                    data = images,
                    prevKey = if (page == STARTING_PAGE_INDEX) null else page - 1,
                    nextKey = if (images.size == 0) null else page + 1
                )
            }
        } catch (exception: IOException) {
            return LoadResult.Error(exception)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Could you please post the sample code which uses "withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {"?

Comment: My original solution is for loading local images from CursorLoader, but also saving and loading additional info from room. I simplify the sample code with just room related code.

Comment: Otherwise just make the Room DAO call a `suspend fun` then you won't have to use `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` in your `PagingSource`.